# Getting Windows to upload .App files as binary file to Dropbox?

Tags: windows-7, mac, dropbox

I notice that whenever I downloaded a .App or compiled a .App file into my Dropbox folder on Windows, Windows uploads the .App file as a folder to Dropbox.

So when my Mac downloads the .App file from Dropbox, it cannot run the .App file and thinks that the file is corrupted.

How can I get Windows to treat and upload .App file just as Mac to Dropbox so that when my Mac downloads the .App file from Dropbox, it could work just fine?

Comment: I would place it in an archive.

Comment: Putting the file into an archive is what I do sometimes. But it is not the most convenient method sometimes. I'm not sure if it has got to do with just Dropbox itself. When I copy the .App file from Windows to a thumbdrive then subsequently transfer it to my Mac, the .App file works. But when I sync the .App file from Windows through Dropbox, my Mac cannot open the .App file.

Comment: [.app is ***not*** a file!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_bundle#OS_X_application_bundles) You're getting confused because OS X makes it appear a single file to the user. If you don't want Dropbox messing with the folder and files inside or any associated metadata, archive it as suggested above.